# Re-instantiate Home Screen Widget when App is Upgraded

Tags: android

I have the following problem:
When the app is upgraded, the active home screen widget goes dead.  It returns to the original XML layout before onUpdate() is ever called, and no longer receives broadcasts.

None of the overridden methods are ever called (onDeleted(), onEnabled(), onDisabled(), or onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()).

I have managed to reinitialize the widget once the app is opened, and leave the default text of the widget as "re-install widget" to inform the user.

However, there is a very important use case that is left out, specifically, when the user doesn't open the app after installing, but wants to use the widget (see the diagram).

Does anyone know a way to detect when the widget dies programmatically, without opening the app?

I know that the running widget code is from the old apk, but the fact that the widget doesn't actually die as soon as the app is installed, and the layout reverts back only when the home screen is navigated to tells me that there should be a way to "get in the middle of that."

Also, I know that the widget doesn't die right away because if the widget is reinitialized before it first dies (going to home screen), it won't have an effect.  That is why the delayed thread is needed to reinitialize the widget when the app is closed.

[image: Current Solution]

Comment: Is there any way you can keep old xml and just add new ones until the user is informed to reinstall widget. I mean you have them both at the same time. Keep old ones and upgrade app for new xmls. Just a thought.

Comment: Informing the user isn't the issue.  I can handle that, but I would prefer not to.  I have a hard time believing that when the Gmail app is upgraded, the widget breaks like this.